# In react chrome extension, instead of opening root route it redirects to other route

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, vue.js

I have created this react chrome extension using vite react, when I open extension it redirects me to login route and if I remove login route it opens blank page without any element inside root div. Normally as webpage all routes works fine but if I use it as extension it opens login page at first, It should render GetStarted page at first. Here is my App.jsx code :

```
import { Routes, Route, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { AnimatePresence } from "framer-motion";
import Auth from "./screens/Auth";
import CreateAccount from "./screens/CreateAccount";
import CreateUsername from "./screens/CreateUsername";
import Dashboard from "./screens/Dashboard";
import GetStarted from "./screens/GetStarted";
import Login from "./screens/Login";
import SeedPharse from "./screens/SeedPharse";
import Transaction from "./screens/Transaction";
import VerifyEmail from "./screens/VerifyEmail";

function App() {
  const location = useLocation();

  return (
    <div className="pb-5">
      <AnimatePresence mode="wait">
        <Routes location={location} key={location.key}>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<GetStarted />} />
          <Route exact path="/auth" element={<Auth />} />
          <Route exact path="/register" element={<CreateAccount />} />
          <Route exact path="/createUsername" element={<CreateUsername />} />
          <Route exact path="/verify" element={<VerifyEmail />} />
          <Route exact path="/dashboard" element={<Dashboard />} />
          <Route exact path="/seedPharse" element={<SeedPharse />} />
          <Route exact path="/transaction" element={<Transaction />} />
          <Route exact path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        </Routes>
      </AnimatePresence>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```